# INSERT record if field value doesn't exist for another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to edit a record (specimen).  On the form is a multiple select list which contains records from a table (topic).  This select list shows topics as selected that exist for the specimen (as identified in  the specimen_topic lookup table) as well as those that can be added to the specimen (from the topic table).

I want to be able to add topics not selected in the list to the lookup table where the topic_fk does not already exist for the specimen_fk:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `specimen_topic_lookup` (
  `specimen_topic_lookup_pk` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `specimen_fk` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `topic_fk` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`specimen_topic_lookup_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

**UPDATE**

I have made the fields specimen_fk and topic_fk UNIQUE.  Using the code below, only one record is created in specimen_table lookup, when two records should have been created (before making the fields UNIQUE, two records were created OK...). I assume this is because `$specimen_pk` is the same value for each insert.

```
foreach($topics as $topic){
    $query_topics = "INSERT IGNORE INTO specimen_topic_lookup(specimen_fk, topic_fk)
    VALUES ('$specimen_pk', '$topic')";
$result_topics = mysql_query($query_topics, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Looks like having UNIQUE is stopping having a record made with the same value (which is at least what I expected...)

**THIS WORKS**

Without having to make specimen_fk OR topic_fk UNIQUE...

```
foreach($topics as $topic){
    $query_topics = "INSERT INTO specimen_topic_lookup(specimen_fk, topic_fk)
    SELECT '$specimen_pk', '$topic'
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM specimen_topic_lookup
                      WHERE specimen_fk = '$specimen_pk' AND topic_fk = '$topic')";
$result_topics = mysql_query($query_topics, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique index on the table and use `insert ignore` or `on duplicate key update`:

```
create unique index specimen_topic_lookup(specimen_fk, topic_fk);

insert ignore into specimen_topic_lookup(specimen_fk, topic_fk)
    select $speciment_fk, $topic_fk;
```

Or, alternatively, you can just do the following without the unique index:

```
insert into specimen_topic_lookup(specifmen_fk, topic_fk)
    select $speciment_fk, $topic_fk
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1
                      from specimen_topic_lookup
                      where specimen_fk = $specimen_fk and topic_fk = $topic_fk
                     );
```

Comment: If I make specimen_fk or topic_fk unique, then I won't be able to add records when these fields have values that already exist in other records.  The uniqueness needs to be on a match between these fields

Comment: @PeterBrowne . . . The uniqueness is on the *combination* of the two fields, not on each one individually.

Comment: See edit in OP..making the fields unique results in only one record being inserted instead of two...I assume this is because $specimen_pk is the same value...

Comment: @GordonLinoff...your alternative solution works fine...many thanks!! See edited OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSERT IGNORE` statement. This will insert any rows that do not violate the unique key, and ignore the ones that do.